# End to end encryption with database

Tags: encryption, public-key-encryption

So I am developing a end-to-end chat platform and have some questions.

1. When a user creates a account on my chat-platform, is it safe enough to store the public key for that user into the database?
2. By having the public key into the db, I can then send a users public key to another user, by doing that, the system can encrypt a message with the public key, which only the receiver can decrypt because the receiver has the secret key.
3. My issue is, how should the secret key be created and stored? Should it be stored into the DB? And should it be encrypted with the user login info? So only a user that knows their user login can get the secret key - so all messages sent to them, can only be decrypted by them on the client-side?

I am not sure how to solve the secret key thing, how to store it and so on. How should it be solved?

Comment: You're on the right track but there are many, many details to get right that you probably aren't aware of yet. Unfortunately, the question seems more like a tutorial crypto/security design question than a programming one, and I think too broad for stackoverflow.

Comment: Do you have any articles or something that can explain this?

Comment: When you’re speaking of *end-to-end* encryption, the secret key must not be stored in a central database (which I assume you refer to), but only on the user’s *end* device.

Comment: Yes, and my question is, how is it done right? Assume if the user gets a new device? How should i give them the secret key, if its in not stored DB?

Comment: Its easy to store the private key on first sign in, but what if the user deletes the app or if the user gets a new device?